# how to remove a condition from an expression IQueryable object in C#

Tags: linq, lambda, expression, iqueryable

I have an IQueryable object sth like;

```
IQueryable<People> query = DemoData.Where(x => true);

query = query.Where(p=> p.Nation == Nation); // query indicates people from a Nation now.

/* 
.
.
some code
.
.
*/

query = query.RemoveWhere(p=> p.Nation == Nation); // this is what I want to have
// query indicates all Nation now.
```

I do want to be able to remove a condition from the query. I tried to express above. Is that possible?

Comment: While it is possible, for which purpose it is needed?

Comment: I receive this object as including some conditions already, I need to remove some conditions, an it is kindda dynamic. I do wonder, is it possible to remove any condition (or have a new instance without that condition)?

Comment: It is EF Core queryable?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10592424/861716) should do it with some minor changes.

Comment: @GertArnold, not minor. At least `ExpressionEqualityComparer` from EF Core will be needed, otherwise it is hard to compare expressions.

Comment: @Svyatoslav I did try that modified code with EF-core 6, with success, but I must admit I don't fully understand the visitor logic because I don't exactly know how a `node` is constructed. That's why I don't post it as an answer. But AFAIKS there's no expression comparison involved, it's just that a node is removed from the tree. Of course I could easily have missed something.

Comment: @GertArnold, it is needed to find `p => p.Nation == Nation` pattern in expression tree and accurately replace with `True` constant.

Comment: OK yes, if exactly *that* expression should be removed. I assumed it could work for the asker to simply remove the Where node(s) at the beginning of the code (forgot to mention that). But it doesn't look like it. @AliCAKIL?